# Code coverage in Xcode without tests (for manual run)

Tags: ios, xcode, code-coverage

Code Coverage is commonly used with tests in Xcode. I would like to use it for manually executed app. Can I do it, possibly with third-party tools?

For example: I build and launch the app on device, perform some actions with it and then look at code coverage results.

Comment: So you basically want to see what parts of the code get reached during a normal run!? Note that this information is probably not worth anything since you can never be sure to have used every possible action and encountered every potential eventuality...!

Comment: @luk2302 yes, exactly. The coverage results are useful to check that performed manual tests have covered all scenarios. So, for example, after manual run we see what code pieces were covered and what pieces should be tested to be sure they work correctly. Let me tell again, my app is very content-specific, so I can't record UI actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was suggested by someone here: https://github.com/SlatherOrg/slather/issues/209

*You could try having a XCUITest that sleeps forever, then manually use the app, and see if on termination the coverage files are generated.*

I simply tried the solution and it worked perfectly for me:

```
class FooTests: XCTestCase {
    
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()
    }
    
    func testBalances() {
        sleep(30)
        XCTAssert(true)
    }
}
```

After the test succeeded on `XCTAssert(true)`, I could see the code coverage for the manual use cases. You can play around with the `sleep(30)` to match your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you might have already figured it out, but it was possible before Xcode7. The way we achieved this was, to set the "Instrument Program Flow" and "Generate Test Coverage files" flags to Yes, on your project, and later add a "flush" code somewhere inside you application, to write the coverage data files. This "flushing" part actually writes the coverage data files, which can be used later by other tools such as gcovr or lcov, to get your coverage data. Once you interact with the app, either manually or through automated tests, the coverage data gets written.

However, with Xcode7, looks like the coverage data is limited to only Xcode unit tests. I am still trying to figure out, if there is any way to gather the coverage data, by interacting with the application manually, or through automated tests.

Comment: I've read about old-way approach with `gcovr` but interesting in new way in Xcode7. There must be some toolset under the hood by which Xcode7 generates coverage reports for XCTests but I can't find useful info about it. Please let me know if you find something useful.

Comment: This is a very old Question and Answer, but - how exactly do you "flush" the repord data out? Are there any bits of code floating around that do this, allowing coverage to be collected via toggles to the Xcode scheme, app execution, a "flush" as mentioned here, then I can just process the report? Hoping for a nice CI solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Code coverage will record which parts of your code your test have run. But you could Build some UITests which would preform some actions as you said. UI can record UI tests to repeat the actions you perform on the simulator then when you run the test it will repeat what you did. The coverage will then show which parts of the code where excited during the UITests.

Look for some info on UITesting in Xcode 7. There is a good demo in one of the developer sessions from wwdc15

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=406

Comment: Thanks, but it's not exactly what I want. My app is very content-specific, so I can't record UI actions. In general code coverage works with any code execution, including manual run. Looks like in Xcode they limit it's usage only to tests. I'm looking for approach that works with manual run: user interacts with app and then we see what code was executed during this run.