# Xcode and Code Coverage

Tags: c++, xcode, code-coverage

My application was initially not written for the Mac platform, so it has it's own unit-test system which can be triggered by a command-line. Is it possible to make use of the code coverage support in Xcode by just executing it?

I tried to make it run as a *UnitTest* which triggers the 'main(...)' function of my application manually (see code block), but since this process is started by the application 'xctest' a lot of things are missing like resources from my application bundle, etc (incorrect or wrong paths, ...).

```
- (void)testExample {
  int main(int argc, char* argv[]);
  main(...);
}
```

Is there any way just to tell Xcode that my application should be started so it can output the code coverage that can be reviewed inside Xcode?

Comment: I have posted a solution to a similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63786744/733168

Answer (score 2):

I didn't use XCode coverage tools but I used gcov before. Anyway in [this article](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/weve-got-you-covered/) there is information how to create llvm coverage report. So you can use your unit-test system with llvm's coverage flags and then create .profdata report with llvm-profdata tool.

As I understand Xcode's code coverage tool also creating .profdata report and uses it. I have no straightforward solution but you may find something with this information. If you find a way to make Xcode uses your .profdata it's done :)

Comment: does this work for C++? The article seems to be for ObjC and Swift

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso this suggestion is not proven to be working with C++ :/ If you want to see the coverage for your C++ code you can use `gcov`. I'm not sure how you will do that with Xcode tools though.

Comment: I've really been struggling to get things working with my C++ project. Trying `gcov` but getting it to work with Xcode is a pain.